# Altering foreign key

Tags: sql, db2, foreign-keys, db2-luw

Is there a way to add ON DELETE CASCADE option to an existing foreign key in DB2 10.5 without dropping and recreating said key?

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot alter in this manner, you must drop and recreate.